# Why Firebase Firestore Collection Group query showing Permission Error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here is my firestore schema.

```
products_clone (collection)
    |
    |-- productId_1 (document)
    |     |-- idStore: "StoreID_1"
    |     |-- productName: "Product Name 1"
    |     |-- is_exist: true
    |     |-- category: "Category 1"
    |     |-- // other product details
    |     |
    |     |-- prices (subcollection)
    |           |
    |           |-- priceId_1 (document)
    |           |     |-- storeName: "Store Name A"
    |           |     |-- price: 10.5
    |           |     |-- // other price details
    |           |
    |           |-- priceId_2 (document)
    |                 |-- storeName: "Store Name B"
    |                 |-- price: 8.99
    |                 |-- // other price details
    |
    |-- productId_2 (document)
    |     |-- idStore: "StoreID_2"
    |     |-- productName: "Product Name 2"
    |     |-- is_exist: false
    |     |-- category: "Category 2"
    |     |-- // other product details
    |     |
    |     |-- prices (subcollection)
    |           |
    |           |-- priceId_3 (document)
    |           |     |-- storeName: "Cool Store"
    |           |     |-- price: 7.25
    |           |     |-- // other price details
    |           |
    |           |-- priceId_4 (document)
    |                 |-- storeName: "Store Name D"
    |                 |-- price: 9.75
    |                 |-- // other price details
    |
    |-- // more products
```

I am facing Permission Error while fetching data using collectionGroup query.

**

> Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient
> permissions., cause=null}

**

Here is my code through which I am trying to achive the result.

```
 Future<void> rankStoresByPriceTotal() async {
      try {
         QuerySnapshot productPricesSnapshot = await _fireStore
          .collectionGroup('prices')
          .where('storeName', isEqualTo: "Cool Store")
          .get();

      productPricesSnapshot.docs.forEach((priceSnapshot) {
          print(priceSnapshot['price']);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error ranking stores: $e');
    }

  }
```

and here are my firestore security rules which I have changed.

```
  // Allow read access to the products_clone collection
    match /products_clone/{document} {
      allow create: if true;
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
      allow delete: if true;
      
    // Allow write access to the prices subcollection within the products_clone document
      match  /prices/{priceId} {
        allow read, write, create, delete: if true;
      }

    }
```

I have even tried this as well.

```
   // Allow read access to the prices subcollection within the products_clone collection
    match /products_clone/{document}/prices/{priceId} {
      allow read, write, create, delete: if true;
    }
```

But nothing worked, so please help me to figure out the issue.

Comment: The first set of rules will have no effect on any collection group query. The second should.  Please edit the question to show the entire set of rules so that we can see they are structured correctly.

Comment: A query on a Firestore collection will check against a `list` rule, which is undefined here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collection group query reads from all documents of a given name, no matter where they are in the database.

That means that for a collection group query, you need rules of the form:

```
match /{path=**}/attractions/{docid} {
  allow read;
}
```

So the last part (`attractions/{docid}`) means that I have a collection group query on all collections named `attractions`. The first part (`{path=**}`) allows the user to run this anywhere in the database

There is no way to secure so that the user can only read from `/products_clone/*/prices/*`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It worked like a charm and surprisingly I had figured out the way on my own. 